# MariaDB docker container on CentOS won't start

Tags: centos, docker, mariadb, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose:

```
version: "2"
services:
  webserver:
    image: orsolin/docker-php-5.3-apache
    environment:
      ALLOW_OVERRIDE: "true"
      HTTP_PROXY: "${HTTP_PROXY}"
      HTTPS_PROXY: "${HTTPS_PROXY}"
      NO_PROXY: "${NO_PROXY}"
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html/

  db:
    image: centos/mariadb-102-centos7
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql/:rw
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: *redacted*
      MYSQL_USER: *redacted*
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: *redacted*
      MYSQL_DATABASE: *redacted*
      HTTP_PROXY: "${HTTP_PROXY}"
      HTTPS_PROXY: "${HTTPS_PROXY}"
      NO_PROXY: "${NO_PROXY}"
    ports:
      - "8889:3306"

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    environment:
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_DB_DRIVER: mysql
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_DB_HOST: mariadb
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_DB_NAME: adminer
      ADMINER_DESIGN: nette
      ADMINER_PLUGINS: tables-filter tinymce
      HTTP_PROXY: "${HTTP_PROXY}"
      HTTPS_PROXY: "${HTTPS_PROXY}"
      NO_PROXY: "${NO_PROXY}"
    ports:
      - "8282:8080"
```

After I run docker-compose up -d, the container keeps on restarting and I can see the following when running `docker logs --tail 50 --follow --timestamps 01e2489d4526`

```
2019-07-11T10:03:45.554517000Z 2019-07-11 10:03:45 140548938721472 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-07-11T10:03:45.559329000Z 2019-07-11 10:03:45 140548938721472 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-07-11T10:03:45.559835000Z 2019-07-11 10:03:45 140548938721472 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Permission denied
2019-07-11T10:03:45.560319000Z 2019-07-11 10:03:45 140548938721472 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock ?
2019-07-11T10:03:45.560796000Z 2019-07-11 10:03:45 140548938721472 [ERROR] Aborting
```

And this is the `docker ps` output:CONTAINER ID        IMAGE

```
    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                    NAMES
8d7e8d571a1b        orsolin/docker-php-5.3-apache   "apache2-foreground"     7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes                   0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp     docker_webserver_1
5f0b1bb872c7        adminer                         "entrypoint.sh doc..."   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes                   0.0.0.0:8282->8080/tcp   docker_adminer_1
01e2489d4526        centos/mariadb-102-centos7      "container-entrypo..."   7 minutes ago       Restarting (1) 2 minutes ago                            docker_db_1
```

How would I fix this, keeping in mind that I will need to be able to connect to the mariadb container from the other containers as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When SELinux is enabled, your containers' volumes should be placed in subdirectories of `/var/lib/docker/volumes`. Volumes in your home directory will have SELinux contexts that do not allow Docker containers to access them.

Comment: This is likely the issue. I quit wasting anymore time on it as I already lost 4-5 hours going back and forth. In the end I installed Ubuntu Server. Problem solved :))

Answer (score 1):

You need to shutdown the container, delete `./mysql/mysql.sock` from the host and start it again. For some reason there already is a socket file there and it needs to be removed to start the service correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear, you either have to stop your other mysql service or change the port in your config file:

[mysqld]

port= 1234

Comment: There isnt another mysql service running. The error is inside the docker container.